# Xamarin form google login

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am making an cross platform xamarin form app and I want to authenticate a user with a google login. How can i do that with the google api? I want to do this preferably with something like json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Xamarin.Auth API for authentication. It has a very trivial set of APIs.

reference - https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth

Comment: can you be specific on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Shahabuddin Vansiwala You have to mention RedirectURL on google developer console

Comment: Yes, I have add RedirectURL on google developer console. RedirectURL is : https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me